# Nested COUNTIF in a IF formula for text or generic values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Have this formulera that doesn't work for me but does for a friend who seems to have the same version of excel as me in the same language

It goes:

```
=OM(B2=B1,"",ANTAL.OM($B$2:$B$65000,B2))
```

**In english:**

```
=IF(B2=B1,"",COUNTIF($B$2:$B$65000,B2))
```

Where B column is company SSN.
B2 = first company SSN.
$B$65000 = last row to match. In this case 79000+.

The purpose is quite simple. I want a column that shows how many times a value is repeated in column B. Each time it occurs in B, it's to be presented in this column.

For instance, with this formula my friend gets 4 when a company SSN is listed 4 times in the B column, on each row in the column the formula was pasted.

We are talking about a sheet with 79000+ rows, knowing each range for each company is not an option.

For the life of me I don't get why it's working for my friend but not me.

Edit: Here is sample data. I can't show when it's not working because I can't save the file with this formula. Regnr = Company SSN, Column B.

[Sample data](https://ufile.io/mpt93)

Link to a working screenshot in swedish from my friend where OM is IF and ANTAL.OM is COUNTIF

[Working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XobP6.png)

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work for you"?  Do you get an error?  Can you post sample data? That's a very simple formula but without seeing an example of it _not_ working, as well as what it _should_ be doing, it is hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: For this to work the expectation is that the SSNs are grouped together and your formula will give you a count only on the first row of each group. Are your SSNs grouped? Do you only want the answer on the first row of each group? If not then you might want to remove the IF function and just use COUNTIF on each row

Comment: If you everything's exactly same as you have mentioned I would check calculation options under formula tab and make sure that it's set to automatic.

Comment: Added sample data and a screenshot of working example. The SSNs are grouped in the sense that they occur together in a range of X rows. They are never repeated further down the sheet.

Comment: @ImranMalek: it's set to automatic.

Comment: @ashleedawg : uploaded sample data, see edit

Comment: Replace `$B$2:$B$65000` with `$B:$B`